# Validação pela API ViaCep

Tags: javascript, cep

Estou tentando fazer a validação dos dados não somente pelo CEP(codigo descrito abaixo), gostaria de fazer a outra verificação, quando o cliente não sabe o cep e encontra o mesmo buscando pelos campos UF, rua e cidade.
O site da api é https://viacep.com.br/

ViaCEP Webservice

```
<!-- Adicionando Javascript -->
<script type="text/javascript" >

function limpa_formulário_cep() {
        //Limpa valores do formulário de cep.
        document.getElementById('rua').value=("");
        document.getElementById('bairro').value=("");
        document.getElementById('cidade').value=("");
        document.getElementById('uf').value=("");
        document.getElementById('ibge').value=("");
}

function meu_callback(conteudo) {
    if (!("erro" in conteudo)) {
        //Atualiza os campos com os valores.
        document.getElementById('rua').value=(conteudo.logradouro);
        document.getElementById('bairro').value=(conteudo.bairro);
        document.getElementById('cidade').value=(conteudo.localidade);
        document.getElementById('uf').value=(conteudo.uf);
        document.getElementById('ibge').value=(conteudo.ibge);
    } //end if.
    else {
        //CEP não Encontrado.
        limpa_formulário_cep();
        alert("CEP não encontrado.");
    }
}

function pesquisacep(valor) {

    //Nova variável "cep" somente com dígitos.
    var cep = valor.replace(/\D/g, '');

    //Verifica se campo cep possui valor informado.
    if (cep != "") {

        //Expressão regular para validar o CEP.
        var validacep = /^[0-9]{8}$/;

        //Valida o formato do CEP.
        if(validacep.test(cep)) {

            //Preenche os campos com "..." enquanto consulta webservice.
            document.getElementById('rua').value="...";
            document.getElementById('bairro').value="...";
            document.getElementById('cidade').value="...";
            document.getElementById('uf').value="...";
            document.getElementById('ibge').value="...";

            //Cria um elemento javascript.
            var script = document.createElement('script');

            //Sincroniza com o callback.
            script.src = 'https://viacep.com.br/ws/'+ cep + '/json/?callback=meu_callback';

            //Insere script no documento e carrega o conteúdo.
            document.body.appendChild(script);

        } //end if.
        else {
            //cep é inválido.
            limpa_formulário_cep();
            alert("Formato de CEP inválido.");
        }
    } //end if.
    else {
        //cep sem valor, limpa formulário.
        limpa_formulário_cep();
    }
};

</script>
</head>

<body>
<!-- Inicio do formulario -->
  <form method="get" action=".">
    <label>Cep:
    <input name="cep" type="text" id="cep" value="" size="10" maxlength="9"
           onblur="pesquisacep(this.value);" /></label><br />
    <label>Rua:
    <input name="rua" type="text" id="rua" size="60" /></label><br />
    <label>Bairro:
    <input name="bairro" type="text" id="bairro" size="40" /></label><br />
    <label>Cidade:
    <input name="cidade" type="text" id="cidade" size="40" /></label><br />
    <label>Estado:
    <input name="uf" type="text" id="uf" size="2" /></label><br />
    <label>IBGE:
    <input name="ibge" type="text" id="ibge" size="8" /></label><br />
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Não é possível utilizar o site supracitado para encontrar o CEP, neste caso você terá que fazer uma requisição para o site do Correios e simular a ação.

Comment: Pelo descrito no site produtor da api tem como fazer a requisição, pegando as informações no campo input e trazer as informações via uma html.

Comment: Tbm procurei um sistema que me informasse o CEP quando eu inserisse Logradouro ou Cidade, mas não achei

Comment: Você pode fazer a request para este caminho: 
https://viacep.com.br/ws/UF/Cidade/RUA/json/
 Ele vai retornar oJSON com as ruas dentro da cidade informada contendo o CEP, desta forma você conseguirá pegar o cep correto.

Comment: Teria a resolução em código ?

Comment: @LucasBrogni, é só ler o manual! eu não havia feito e estava quebrando a cabeça e não tinha lido isto, que fica lá embaixo na página. Grato! Retorna um Array de até 50 objetos cujo CEP tem aquele logradouro. Embora não permita wildcard no logradouro, se buscar `Jose` virá `Jose` e `José`